# React/Redux Passing state change <Picker>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using the react-native Picker component and having trouble updating the global state when the value changes.

I haven't used Redux before and read it is one of the only solutions to pass state to another component which isn't parent/child. I have a Network.js file which deals with an API. I want to pass a state to the Network.js when a user picks a value it updates the state.

Here is my code for the App component and PageOne Component
App.js. Many Thanks

```js
const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if(action.type === "REGIONAL_ID") {
    return {
      regionId: state.regionId
    };
  }
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BottomTabNav />
      </Provider>
    )
  }  
}
```

PageOne.js

```js
class PageOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  changeRegion = (regId) => {
    // How to add/dispatch the regId to the prop 
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'REGIONAL_ID' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View >
      <Picker
 selectedValue={this.state.regionId}
 style={{ flex:1, height: 50, width: SCREEN_WIDTH }}
 onValueChange={itemValue => this.changeRegion(itemValue)}>
 <Picker.Item label="One" value='1' />
 <Picker.Item label="Two" value='2' />
      </Picker>
    </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  regionId: state.regionId
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PageOne)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App.js, you should return a *new* state:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  if(action.type === "REGIONAL_ID") {
     return {
        regionId: action.regionId
      };
    }
    return state;
}
```

In PageOne.js, just do:

```
changeRegion = (regId) => {
  // How to add/dispatch the regId to the prop 
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'REGIONAL_ID', regionId: regId });
}
```

This will update the regionId in the state.